# How to detach a rigidbody on particular touch

Tags: unityscript, detach

I have an issue in detaching single rigidbody(small ball),when i touch on one blue sprite,ball attached to the sprite should be detached but when i hit on any one sprite both the balls are detaching.please help me out.Thanks in advance

```
enter code here
var ball : Rigidbody;
var Position:Transform;

function Update () {
        for (var i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++)
        {
           if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            //if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1")) 
            {    
                // var touchPos : Vector3 = Input.GetTouch(i).position;

                 var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.GetTouch(i).position);
                 var hit : RaycastHit;

                    if (Physics.Raycast (ray, hit)){   
                            move();
                            Debug.Log();
                            //Destroy(hit.rigidbody);
                        }
            }   
        }
    }
function move(){
     //var clone:Rigidbody;
     //clone=Instantiate(ball, transform.position,Quaternion.identity);
     ball.useGravity=false;
     ball.AddForce(transform.TransformDirection(0.0f,10.0f,0.0f)*-20);
     ball.transform.parent=null;
     //Destroy(ball.gameObject,5);
     Debug.Log("button");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you're calling your 'move' function anytime you detect something with the Raycast.

You should filter you raycast hit to ensure you are calling your function with an specific touch.

```
    if (Physics.Raycast (ray, hit)){
                       if(hit.transform.name.equals("BlueBall"))  
                        move();
                        Debug.Log();
                        //Destroy(hit.rigidbody);
                    }
```

Hope you'll find useful.